# Typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cssRules') Angular SSR

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, angular15, angular-ssr

After angular upgrade from 11 to 15 started getting this error. I am using nodejs version 16.15.1

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cssRules')
at appendStylesTo (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:5375112)
at /Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:5374199
at Map.forEach ()
at injectStyles (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:5374181)
at Object.26121 (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:5377125)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:9135588)
at Object.10070 (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:5307574)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:9135588)
at Object.67022 (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:5589338)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/mohsinjavaid/Desktop/photele/photele.com/dist/server/main.js:1:9135588)

Package.json:

"dependencies": {
"@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/localize": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-server": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
"@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.7",
"@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.7",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.7",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.7",
"@fullcalendar/moment-timezone": "^6.1.7",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.7",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.0",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.1.0",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.27.0",
"@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.26",
"alife-file-to-base64": "0.0.4",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.11.0",
"angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
"angularx-social-login": "^4.1.0",
"autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.2",
"color2k": "^2.0.0",
"compression": "^1.7.4",
"domino": "^2.1.6",
"dotenv": "^16.0.0",
"express": "^4.15.2",
"gzipper": "^7.2.0",
"heroku-ssl-redirect": "^0.1.1",
"jquery": "^3.6.2",
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
"ngx-image-cropper": "^4.0.1",
"ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.2",
"ngx-stripe": "^13.0.0",
"ngx-ui-loader": "^11.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"primeicons": "^6.0.1",
"primeng": "^11.4.5",
"rxjs": "~7.4.0",
"stripe-angular": "^1.7.0",
"swiper": "^6.8.4",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"uuid": "^8.3.2",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.8",
"@angular/cli": "^15.2.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
"@nguniversal/builders": "^15.1.0",
"@types/express": "^4.17.8",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-marbles": "~0.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.4.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "^3.3.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.9.5"
}

I tried updating other dependencies and also did clean npm install but still same error

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution, I face the same issue...

Comment: I downgraded fullCalendar from 6.1.7 to 6.1.5 and my issue was resolved.